# SQL - select identical value not listed in GROUP BY

Tags: sql, group-by

In SQL, is it somehow possible to select an **identical** value (if existent) of a column which is **not** listed within the `GROUP BY` clause?

In other words, I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
SELECT a, IDENTICAL_VALUE(b) 
FROM x 
GROUP BY a;
```

Whereby `IDENTICAL_VALUE` should return the value of `x.b` if it's identical (i.e. unique), and `NULL` otherwise.

Comment: identical to what? to a?

Comment: Identical in the sense of "unique" - i.e. when all values of `b` which are grouped by `a` are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can count the distinct values and just return the `MAX` if there's only one.

```
SELECT a, 
       CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT b) =1 THEN MAX(b) END
FROM x 
GROUP BY a;
```

Or, alternatively (may be better performing as no need to actually identify the distinct values)

```
SELECT a, 
       CASE WHEN MAX(b) = MIN(b) THEN MAX(b) END
FROM x 
GROUP BY a;
```

Comment: That's a nice solution, but it should be noted that this will ignore any `NULL` values within the `b` column (i.e. if the `b` column contained the two values `1` and `NULL`, this would return `1` as result, not `NULL`).

Comment: @emkey08 nulls aren't values. [Null is a marker for a missing value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL))  If you want to count them as values it isn't clear what the approach would be. `null` generally isn't regarded as equal to `null` so would two nulls be one distinct value or two? In any event you can compare `count(*)` to `count(b)` to identify whether or not there are any `null` (and if so how many) and change the logic as needed.